# Confusion about inheritance in python OOP

Tags: python

Source Code:

```py
 class Shape():
   def __init__(self, name="unknown", sides=0, dimensions=0):
     self.sides = sides
     self.dimensions = dimensions
     self.name = name
     
   def desc(self):
     print("A", self.name, "has", self.sides, "sides and", self.dimensions, "dimensions")
     
 class shape_2D(Shape):
   def __init__(self, name, sides, dimensions):
     super().__init__(name, sides, 2)
     
 square = shape_2D(name="square", sides = 4, dimensions=2)
 square.desc()
 
 class shape_3D(shape_2D):
   def __init__(self, name, sides, dimensions):
     super().__init__(name, sides, 3)
 
 cube = shape_3D(name="cube", sides = 6, dimensions = 3)
 cube.desc()
```

Output: running this program outputs

```
A square has 4 sides and 2 dimensions
A cube has 6 sides and 2 dimensions
```

Why isn't this outputting 3 dimensions for the cube class? Similarly, is there a way I can code this so I don't need to add the dimensions when defining cube or square, I thought the whole point of using a class is that it will inherit the dimensions from that class so I wouldn't need to define the number of dimensions. Also, apologies if this is terrible coding, I'm very new to this sort of thing!

Comment: Because `shape_2D.__init__` ignores the passed `dimensions` and always overrides it with `2`.

Comment: First of all, it doesn't make sense for `shape_3d` to inherit `shape_2d`. The whole point of defining generic `shape` would be to extract the common logic there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `shape_3D` to construct a new instance of the class, this will call `shape_3D.__init__`, which will call `shape_2D.__init__`, and this call overrides the dimension to 2.

To achieve what you want to do, you need make `shape_3D` inherit from `Shape` directly. This should make sense, because a 3D shape is particular type of shape, not 2d shape.

Hence, to achieve what you want here, you will need to do something like this:

```py
class shape_2D(Shape):
  def __init__(self, name, sides):
    super().__init__(name, sides, dimensions=2)


class shape_3D(Shape):
  def __init__(self, name, sides):
    super().__init__(name, sides, dimensions=3)
```

Notice how I have remove the parameter `dimensions` from the constructor of `shape_2D` and `shape_3D`.

Then, you can create your objects as so:

```py
>>> square = shape_2D(name="square", sides=4)
>>> square.desc()
A square has 4 sides and 2 dimensions
>>> cube = shape_3D(name="cube", sides=6)
>>> cube()
A cube has 6 sides and 3 dimensions.
```

As a side note, consider following the PEP8 [naming conventions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names) regarding class names.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your `shape_2d` and `shape_3d` have `dimension` parameter to `__init__` that is not used and instead you pass fixed value to super's init. Since your `shape_3d` inherits from `shape_2d` for some reason, the `3` you pass is ignored and `2` is used in its place. Remove the pointless parameter and change the inheritance so it makes more sense:

```
class Shape():
    def __init__(self, name="unknown", sides=0, dimensions=0):
        self.sides = sides
        self.dimensions = dimensions
        self.name = name
        
    def desc(self):
        return f"A {self.name} has {self.sides} sides and {self.dimensions} dimensions"
    
class shape_2D(Shape):
    def __init__(self, name, sides):
        super().__init__(name, sides, 2)
    
square = shape_2D(name="square", sides = 4)
print(square.desc())

class shape_3D(Shape):
    def __init__(self, name, sides):
        super().__init__(name, sides, 3)

cube = shape_3D(name="cube", sides = 6)
print(cube.desc())
```